# I want all records from table 1 and only a few selected values from the second table. How can I write a query in SQL to get the results?

Tags: sql

I want all records from table 1 and only a few selected values from the second table. How can I write a query in SQL to get the results? I am not getting desired result from the following query.

```
select a.id, a.amt, b.ac from table1 as a 
left join table2 as b on a.id=b.id 
where b.ac in ('ac11', 'ac14')

Table1          Table2  
id      amt     id      ac
A123    400     A123    ac11
A124    500     A124    ac12
A125    600     A125    ac13
A126    700     A126    ac14
                
Desired Result              
Table3              
id      amt ac      
A123    400 ac11        
A124    500         
A125    600         
A126    700 ac14
```

Comment: What is the condition used to fetch those selected records in the second table?

Comment: `AND b.ac in ('ac11', 'ac14')`, to get true left join result move the outer table filtering to the ON clause...

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got one product specific answer...)

Comment: I am using squirrel sql client v3.7.1, can you write full query.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this one. It's easy for you.

select a.id, a.amt, isnull(b.ac,'') as ac from Table1 as a
left join Table2 as b on a.id=b.id

Answer (score 0):

Just move where statement to the join:

```
select a.id, a.amt, b.ac from table1 as a 
left join table2 as b on a.id=b.id and b.ac in ('ac11', 'ac14')
```